# flip an image vertically using loops in python

Tags: python, image, loops, flip

n my function there are the two options: flipping vertically or horizontally. vertically if vertically = True. The horizontal part is correct however, when i try to flip an image vertically, the image i get ends up being just 42% flipped. I don´t know which part of my code is wrong. Can you give me some guidance?

```
def flip(image,vertical=False):

    height = len(image)
    width  = len(image[0])

    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width//2):
            pixel = image[row][col]
            image[row][col] = image[row][width - col - 1]
            image[row][width - col - 1] = pixel
            if vertical == True:
                image[row][col] = image[height-row-1][width - col - 1]
                image[height-row-1][width - col - 1] = pixel

    return True
```

Comment: You just aren't thinking about it what you're doing.  By the time you get to the middle of the image, you've already overwritten the bottom half with scanlines from the top.  If you want to flip both H and V, then just swap the very first pixel with the very last pixel, and continue on until you reach the middle.

Comment: Better place the `if vertical` at the beginning and write independent code for the vertical case where you basically have to switch the roles of `row` and `col`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the penultimate line from

```
image[height-row-1][width - col - 1] = pixel
```

to

```
image[height-row-1][width] = pixel
```

However, it's probably better to rethink the algorithm and either flip horizontally or flip vertically. The method in the question flips horizontally then, if vertical is True, tries to undo the horizontal flip and simultaneously do a vertical flip (and, I think, misses the fact that 'pixel' is from the unflipped coordinate system). This makes the code difficult to read.

An even better solution would be to reverse with the slice notation:

```
image[row] = image[row][::-1]
```

or, for the other axis:

```
image = image[::-1]
```

(I'm answering on my phone so can't check the code, apologies for any typos)